# Running EC2 instances using ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I would like to get only running EC2 instances. The playbook below is throwing the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution."}
```

Is this an error in the environment?

Here is the playbook.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
      region: us-west-1
  tasks:
    - name: Gathers facts (instance metadata) about remote hosts remote ec2 (all)
      ec2_instance_facts:
       region: "{{ region }}"
       filters:
          "tag:Name": "Security-VPC*"

      register: ec2_metadata
    - name: print ec2 facts of TEST TEST
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ec2_metadata.instances | selectattr('state','equalto','running') | list  }}"
```

Comment: Hello, I understand this is your 1st question on Stackoverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit the question to provide the missing information (don't answer in comment). Example of improvement: version of ansible.

Comment: … You could also say at which tasks the error appears.

Comment: have you tried to use `--syntax-check` to see any potential error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the state when gathering ec2 instances facts as you did already for the tag, and when passing the facts to `debug` you have to loop over `ec2_metadata.instances`.

This gives this example that works for me.

```
---
- name: test aws ec2
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    region: us-west-1
  tasks:

    - name: Gathers facts (instance metadata) about remote hosts remote ec2 (all)
      ec2_instance_facts:
        region: "{{ region }}"
        filters:
          "tag:Name": "Security-VPC*"
          instance-state-name: running
      register: ec2_metadata

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ ec2_metadata.instances }}"
...
```

I get this output (obviously my servers don't match your filter)

```
$ ansible-playbook ec2_instance_facts.yml 

PLAY [test aws ec2] ****************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathers facts (instance metadata) about remote hosts remote ec2 (all)] **************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Thank you Baptistem.
If I need instance-id, below script is not working. Anything wrong?

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.instance_id }}"
      with_items: "{{ ec2_metadata.instances }}"

Comment: it is hard to say what is missing from the code you just gave, but in theory that should work